# Is there a way to set a worker name with xmr-stak-cpu?

Tags: monerod

Just for fun, spun up 8 of the tiny VPS droplets running Ubuntu 16.04 from digital ocean.

I had already successfully setup a Monero XMR Pool that was built with node.js from zone117x.

I would like to be able to track the stats for each worker, but as far as I know I can't set a worker name with xmr-stak-cpu like other miners

Ex: -u moneroaddresshere.WORKERNAME

Is there anyway for me to do this with xmr-stak-cpu? 
There's no point making a bunch of different monero wallets if the pool is run by me, I just want to see the differences in each VPS's performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append it after your payment address with a +

e.g.:

"wallet_address" : "YOUR_ADDRESS+WORKER_NAME"

most stratum pools should recognize this.

Comment: Did not work for me.  Broke login.  Pool is Monero Ocean, in case it matters.

Comment: Check out monero ocean's FAQ: https://moneroocean.stream/#/help/faq

There it says that their worker "stop sign" is a "." to be put after your address.

Or (and this works also for many other pools / crypro miners) to put your worker name in your miner's password section <miner_name>:<password>.

Comment: @catafish, thx.  I stumbled on the answer.  For monero ocean it's the latter suggestion -   <miner_name>:<password>.
Thanks for replying.